# java.lang.NoSuchMethodError while loading s3

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-sdk

I am running a spark code using `databricks` `jdbc` to read data from `Redshift`, I am able to run the spark program in dev but while running in UAT I am getting below error.

> java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient.disableStrictHostnameVerification

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please add a minimal complete example: https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: This must be library version mismatch error. Check the `classpath` in `UAT`, it must be using different jar version as compared from `dev`.